# Nav Menu and display post count

Tags: menus

Iam looking for a solution that the number of child post displayed, like so:

Parent (14)
- Child
- Child

Parent (2)
- Child

I have played with the custom walker and tried the function with ->count but without luck.

Has someone a solution? Thanks

```
class Count_Post_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names .'>';

        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

        $submenus = $depth == 0 ? get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'show_count' => 1, 'numberposts' => -1,  'meta_query' => array(
       array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => $item->ID,

        ))
 ) ) : false;
        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $submenus ? ' <span class="submenus-count">(' . count( $submenus ) . ')</span>' : '';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the current output?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, I've got the solution to this problem. You can retrieve number of child items right from menu_items retrieved by [wp_get_nav_menu_items](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items). This function retrieves a bunch of post objects containing info about 'menu_item_parent'.

Inside start_el function of Walker_Nav_Menu class, you can try the match agains $item->ID. This way:

```
$locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations['primary'] );
$menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
$count = 0;
foreach( $menu_items as $menu_item ){
    if( $menu_item->menu_item_parent == $item->ID ){
        $count++;           
    }       
}
```

Than you've got the count of children items in $count variable. Here's the full code:

class Count_Post_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

```
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    global $wp_query;
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

    $class_names = $value = '';

    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
    $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
    $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

    /* Code to get children count */
    $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations['primary'] );
    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
    $count = 0;
    foreach( $menu_items as $menu_item ){
        if( $menu_item->menu_item_parent == $item->ID ){
            $count++;           
        }       
    }
    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</a>';
    if( $count > 0 )
        $item_output .= '('.$count.')';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
}
```

}

Comment: Sry, but i mean not to display the count of the child Cateogrys, but of the POSTS inside the Children Categorys. But i try now to find a soloution :)