# Custom Nav Walker menu - Display children count

Tags: menus, walker

I have a custom walker menu.( See the code below)

I would like to have my nav menu like this

```
----------------------------------
Home | link1 | link2 | link3 (5)
----------------------------------
```

Where `5` is the children count of link3.

Can someone help me to implement this?

Here is my current custom nav walker code.

```
<?php
/**
 * Cleaner walker for wp_nav_menu()
 *
 * Walker_Nav_Menu (WordPress default) example output:
 *   <li id="menu-item-8" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
 *   <li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-9"><a href="/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></l
 *
 * Roots_Nav_Walker example output:
 *   <li class="menu-home"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
 *   <li class="menu-sample-page"><a href="/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li>
 */
class Roots_Nav_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
  function check_current($classes) {
    return preg_match('/(current[-_])|active|dropdown/', $classes);
  }

  function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $output .= "\n<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">\n";
  }

  function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
    $item_html = '';
    parent::start_el($item_html, $item, $depth, $args);

    if ($item->is_dropdown && ($depth === 0)) {
      $item_html = str_replace('<a', '<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#"', $item_html);
      $item_html = str_replace('</a>', ' <b class="caret"></b></a>', $item_html);
    }
    elseif (stristr($item_html, 'li class="divider')) {
      $item_html = preg_replace('/<a[^>]*>.*?<\/a>/iU', '', $item_html);
    }
    elseif (stristr($item_html, 'li class="nav-header')) {
      $item_html = preg_replace('/<a[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/iU', '$1', $item_html);
    }

    $output .= $item_html;
  }

  function display_element($element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth = 0, $args, &$output) {
    $element->is_dropdown = !empty($children_elements[$element->ID]);

    if ($element->is_dropdown) {
      if ($depth === 0) {
        $element->classes[] = 'dropdown';
      } elseif ($depth === 1) {
        $element->classes[] = 'dropdown-submenu';
      }
    }

    parent::display_element($element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output);
  }
}

/**
 * Remove the id="" on nav menu items
 * Return 'menu-slug' for nav menu classes
 */
function roots_nav_menu_css_class($classes, $item) {
  $slug = sanitize_title($item->title);
  $classes = preg_replace('/(current(-menu-|[-_]page[-_])(item|parent|ancestor))/', 'active', $classes);
  $classes = preg_replace('/^((menu|page)[-_\w+]+)+/', '', $classes);

  $classes[] = 'menu-' . $slug;

  $classes = array_unique($classes);

  return array_filter($classes, 'is_element_empty');
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'roots_nav_menu_css_class', 10, 2);
add_filter('nav_menu_item_id', '__return_null');

/**
 * Clean up wp_nav_menu_args
 *
 * Remove the container
 * Use Roots_Nav_Walker() by default
 */
function roots_nav_menu_args($args = '') {
  $roots_nav_menu_args['container'] = false;

  if (!$args['items_wrap']) {
    $roots_nav_menu_args['items_wrap'] = '<ul class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>';
  }

  if (current_theme_supports('bootstrap-top-navbar')) {
    $roots_nav_menu_args['depth'] = 3;
  }

  if (!$args['walker']) {
    $roots_nav_menu_args['walker'] = new Roots_Nav_Walker();
  }

  return array_merge($args, $roots_nav_menu_args);
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_args', 'roots_nav_menu_args');
```

Comment: Not sure if duplicate, but here's a very similar Q with solution: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/88419/12615

Comment: @brasofilo Thankyou. I solved it using that answer.

Comment: I find it ridiculous that you can find out if the menu item has children from the `$item` via `$item->has_children` but you can't find out how many children it has?  Would be nice to know this without having to load up nav menu functions that will cause extra burden within the `start_el` function, since everything should be known about the menu at that point already!

Comment: typo, meant `$args->has_children`.  In any case, if you can find out that it has children, why can't we know how many children it has?

Comment: @SolomonClosson You do realise this Q&A is more than 3 years old? WordPress released lot of versions in the last 3 years and improved their codebase. If you would like to improve the code of this Q&A feel free to edit it and submit for review.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
    $item_html = '';
    parent::start_el($item_html, $item, $depth, $args);
    $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations['primary_navigation'] );
    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
    $count = 0;
    foreach( $menu_items as $menu_item ){
        if( $menu_item->menu_item_parent == $item->ID ){
            $count++;           
        }       
    }
    if ($item->is_dropdown) {
      $item_html = str_replace('</a>', ' <span class="badge">'.$count.'</span></a>', $item_html);
    }
    if ($item->is_dropdown && ($depth === 0)) {
      $item_html = str_replace('<a', '<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#"', $item_html);
      $item_html = str_replace('</a>', ' <b class="caret"></b></a>', $item_html);
    }
    elseif (stristr($item_html, 'li class="divider')) {
      $item_html = preg_replace('/<a[^>]*>.*?<\/a>/iU', '', $item_html);
    }
    elseif (stristr($item_html, 'li class="nav-header')) {
      $item_html = preg_replace('/<a[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/iU', '$1', $item_html);
    }

    $output .= $item_html;
  }
```

Comment: Loading up menu items from `start_el` is going to kill your servers performance.  The count of children it has should already be known and be a property of `$item`.  They need to add that property in there, this is RIDICULOUS!

Answer (score 2):

I sort of added onto @Giri's answer by using `array_map` and `array_count_values`. if this helps anyone in the future. I didn't wish to use a counter and a `foreach` loop for something so simple.

```
function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    if ($item->hasChildren) {
        $locations = get_nav_menu_locations(); // Getting the locations of the nav menus array.
        $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations['primary_navigation'] ); // Getting the menu calling the walker from the array.
        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id); // Getting the menu item objects array from the menu.
        $menu_item_parents = array_map(function($o) { return $o->menu_item_parent; }, $menu_items); // Getting the parent ids by looping through the menu item objects array. This will give an array of parent ids and the number of their children.
        $children_count = array_count_values($menu_item_parents)[$item->ID]; // Get number of children menu item has.
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if they changed something or if it's particular to my setup, but I had to use `if ($args->has_children)` rather than `if ($item->hasChildren)`. The rest worked beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest approach to this solution would be to track the number of children from the `display_element` function (where the `$this->has_children` is set) which `Walker_Nav_Menu` uses from the original `Walker` class (along with all other Walker_X classes).

This will allow access to the number of children in your extended `Walker_Nav_Menu` functions `start_el`, `start_lvl`, `end_lvl`, `end_el`, and any other functions nested within the `display_element` scope using `$this->total_children` which will save you having to write this code for all of those functions (if needed) and save a lot of server resources with large `Walker` structures, like so...

```
class Extended_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    public $total_children;

    public function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, &$output ) {
        if ( ! $element ) {
            return;
        }
        $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];
        $id       = $element->$id_field;
        $this->total_children = 0;
        if ( ! empty( $children_elements[ $id ] ) ) {
            $this->total_children = count( $children_elements[ $id ] );
        }
        parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to take a look at what the `$item` variable includes within the`start_el()` function.

For example, the `menu-order` property might be of use to you.

```
function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    echo $item->menu_order;
}
```

This might output something like: `1234` if you have four menu items.